# custom function after grouping data.fame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Given the following data.frame

```
d <- rep(c("a", "b"), each=5)
l <- rep(1:5, 2) 
v <- 1:10

df       <- data.frame(d=d, l=l, v=v*v)
df
   d l   v
1  a 1   1
2  a 2   4
3  a 3   9
4  a 4  16
5  a 5  25
6  b 1  36
7  b 2  49
8  b 3  64
9  b 4  81
10 b 5 100
```

Now I want to add another column after grouping by l. The extra column should contain the value of v_b - v_a

```
   d l   v    e
1  a 1   1    35 (36-1)
2  a 2   4    45 (49-4)
3  a 3   9    55 (64-9)
4  a 4  16    65 (81-16)
5  a 5  25    75 (100-25)
6  b 1  36    35 (36-1)
7  b 2  49    45 (49-4)
8  b 3  64    55 (64-9)
9  b 4  81    65 (81-16)
10 b 5 100    75 (100-25)
```

In paranthesis the way how to calculate the value.

I'm looking for a way using dplyr. So I started with something like this

```
df %.% 
 group_by(l) %.%
 mutate(e=myCustomFunction)
```

But how should I define myCustomFunction? I thought grouping of the data.frame produces another (sub-)data.frame which is a parameter to this function. But it isn't...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I guess this is the `dplyr` equivalent to @jlhoward's `data.table` solution:

```
df %>%
  group_by(l) %>%
  mutate(e = v[d == "b"] - v[d == "a"])
```

#### Edit after comment by OP:

If you want to use a custom function, here's a possible way:

```
myfunc <- function(x) {
  with(x, v[d == "b"] - v[d == "a"])
}

test %>%
  group_by(l) %>%
  do(data.frame(. , e = myfunc(.))) %>%
  arrange(d, l)                   # <- just to get it back in the original order
```

#### Edit after comment by @hadley:

As hadley commented below, it would be better in this case to define the function as

```
f <- function(v, d) v[d == "b"] - v[d == "a"]
```

and then use the custom function `f` inside a `mutate`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(l) %>%
  mutate(e = f(v, d))
```

Thanks @hadley for the comment.

Comment: @beginnR, @agstudy When I want to put `v[d == "b"] - v[d == "a"]` in a function and put only `e=myfunc(v)` into `mutate` this won't work. The function only gets two integers (`str(v)` in myfunc prints `int [1:2] 1 36`). So I lose the other indices.

Comment: @JerryWho see my updated answer. To apply custom functions inside dplyr, you have to use the `do` operator. When you do that, you use `.` to pass the data to your custom function.

Comment: It would be better to make the function `f <- function(v, d) v[d == "b"] - v[d == "a"]` and then do `mutate(e = f(v, d))`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @hadley. I edited my answer with your suggestion to make that clear to anyone who might come across this later on. (I'm only getting started with custom functions inside dplyr chains and my initial thought was to use `do` in such a case)

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %.%   
  group_by(l)  %.%
  mutate(e=diff(v))

# d l   v  e
# 1  a 1   1 35
# 2  a 2   4 45
# 3  a 3   9 55
# 4  a 4  16 65
# 5  a 5  25 75
# 6  b 1  36 35
# 7  b 2  49 45
# 8  b 3  64 55
# 9  b 4  81 65
# 10 b 5 100 75
```

Comment: My real problem is a little bit more complex. So I can't use diff because there are more than just two lines after grouping. Is there a way to use a custom function with mutate? And what are the arguments this function is called with?

Comment: @JerryWho you just wrap diff in a function : `my_diff <- function(x)diff(x)` then you replace diff by my_diff

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach using data tables.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[,e := diff(v), by=l]
```

These approaches using `diff(...)` assume your `data frame` is sorted as in your example. If not, this is a more reliable way to do the same thing.

```
DT[, e := .SD[d == "b", v] - .SD[d == "a", v], by=l]
```

(or) even more directly

```
DT[, e := v[d == "b"] - v[d == "a"], by=l]
```

But if you want to access the entire subset of data and pass it to your custom function, then you can use `.SD`. Also make sure you read about `?.SDcols` from `?data.table`.

Comment: That's great. The symbol .SD is what I was looking for. Is there anything similar in dplyr? I was using plyr, switched to data.table a few weeks ago because of speed. Then I found dplyr and liked it more than data.table. So I hoped I could use just dplyr...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider a non-dplyr option

```
df$e <- with(df, ave(v, l, FUN=function(x) diff(x)))
```

will do the trick. The `ave` function is useful for calculating values for groups of observations.