# dplyr: Use a custom function in summarize() after group_by()

Tags: r, dplyr

How can we use a custom function after `group_by()`?
I checked similar posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127237/custom-function-after-grouping-data-fame), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730774/how-to-use-custom-functions-in-mutate-dplyr?rq=1), and [3](https://medium.com/optima-blog/writing-your-own-dplyr-functions-a1568720db0d)), but my current code returns the same values for all groups.

```
> data
   village     A     Z      Y 
     <chr> <int> <int>   <dbl> 
 1       a     1     1   500     
 2       a     1     1   400     
 3       a     1     0   800  
 4       b     1     0   300  
 5       b     1     1   700  

z <- 1
data %>%
    group_by(village) %>%
    summarize(Y_village = Y_hat_village(., z))

Y_hat_village <- function(data_village, z){
    # Calculate the mean for a specific z in a village
    data_z <- data_village %>% filter(Z==get("z"))
    return(mean(data_z$Y))
}
```

I want to have (500 + 400)/2 = 450 for village "a" and 700 for village "b".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's easier to understand if you start by writing it without an extra function. In that case it would be:

```
df %>%
  group_by(village) %>%
  summarize(Y_village = mean(Y[Z == z]))

## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  village Y_village
#  <fct>       <dbl>
#1 a            450.
#2 b            700.
```

Hence, your function should be something like

```
Y_hat_village <- function(Ycol, Zcol, z){
  mean(Ycol[Zcol == z])
}
```

And then using it:

```
df %>%
  group_by(village) %>%
  summarize(Y_village = Y_hat_village(Y, Z, z))
```

Note that the function I wrote only deals with atomic vectors which you can supply directly from within `summarise`. You don't need to supply the whole data.frame into it.

Comment: Thanks! One follow up question: is it possible to pass a part of tibble into a function? In this case, passing a part of tibble whose village is "a", for example.

Comment: In general, yes. You can pass almost anything into a function, including tibbles or parts of tibbles.

Comment: I tired to pass a part of tibble (by group) using `.` in the original code. But it seems the entire data was passed to the function. How can we specify grouped tibble?

Comment: @user2978524, you should probably ask that as a new question

Comment: @user2978524 `cur_data()` refers to the data in a particular group

Comment: @JoséLuizFerreira, how did you come to find out about cur_data() ??? you saved me from hours of looking in the internet . I would like to read the source/manual where you learned this :)

Comment: @JorgeLopez Here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/grouping.html#cur_group-and-cur_group_id

Comment: Notice that `cur_data` was [deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/deprec-context.html)