# dplyr: passing a grouped tibble to a custom function

Tags: r, dplyr

(The following scenario simplifies my actual situation)
My data comes from villages, and I would like to summarize an outcome variable by a village variable.

```
> data
   village     A     Z      Y 
     <chr> <int> <int>   <dbl> 
 1       a     1     1   500     
 2       a     1     1   400     
 3       a     1     0   800  
 4       b     1     0   300  
 5       b     1     1   700
```

For example, I would like to calculate the mean of `Y` only using `Z==z` by villages. In this case, I want to have (500 + 400)/2 = 450 for village "a" and 700 for village "b".

Please note that the actual situation is more complicated and I cannot directly use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50925734/dplyr-use-a-custom-function-in-summarize-after-group-by/50926037?noredirect=1#comment88854293_50926037), but **the point is I need to pass a grouped tibble and a global variable (z) to my function**.

```
z <- 1 # z takes 0 or 1
data %>%
    group_by(village) %>% # grouping by village
    summarize(Y_village = Y_hat_village(., z)) # pass a part of tibble and a global variable

Y_hat_village <- function(data_village, z){
    # This function takes a part of tibble (`data_village`) and a variable `z`
    # Calculate the mean for a specific z in a village
    data_z <- data_village %>% filter(Z==get("z"))
    return(mean(data_z$Y))
}
```

However,  I found `.` passes entire tibble and the code above returns the same values for all groups.

Comment: I think you're looking for `do`, you can also consider using `split` then `map`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple things you can simplify. One is in your function: since you're passing in a value `z` to the function, you don't need to use `get("z")`. You have a `z` in the global environment that you pass in; or, more safely, assign your z value to a variable with some other name so you don't run into scoping issues, and pass that in to the function. In this case, I'm calling it `z_val`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

z_val <- 1

Y_hat_village2 <- function(data, z) {
  data_z <- data %>% filter(Z == z)
  return(mean(data_z$Y))
}
```

You can make the function call on each group using `do`, which will get you a list-column, and then unnesting that column. Again note that I'm passing in the variable `z_val` to the argument `z`.

```r
df %>%
  group_by(village) %>%
  do(y_hat = Y_hat_village2(., z = z_val)) %>%
  unnest()
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   village y_hat
#>   <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 a         450
#> 2 b         700
```

However, `do` is being deprecated in favor of `purrr::map`, which I am still having trouble getting the hang of. In this case, you can group and nest, which gives a column of data frames called `data`, then map over that column and again supply `z = z_val`. When you unnest the `y_hat` column, you still have the original data as a nested column, since you wanted access to the rest of the columns still.

```r
df %>%
  group_by(village) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(y_hat = map(data, ~Y_hat_village2(., z = z_val))) %>%
  unnest(y_hat)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   village data             y_hat
#>   <chr>   <list>           <dbl>
#> 1 a       <tibble [3 × 3]>   450
#> 2 b       <tibble [2 × 3]>   700
```

Just to check that everything works okay, I also passed in `z = 0` to check for 1. scoping issues, and 2. that other values of z work.

```r
df %>%
  group_by(village) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(y_hat = map(data, ~Y_hat_village2(., z = 0))) %>%
  unnest(y_hat)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   village data             y_hat
#>   <chr>   <list>           <dbl>
#> 1 a       <tibble [3 × 3]>   800
#> 2 b       <tibble [2 × 3]>   300
```

Answer (score 1):

As an extension/modification to @patL's answer, you can also wrap the `tidyverse` solution within `purrr:map` to return a `list` of two `tibble`s, one for each `z` value:

```
z <- c(0, 1);
map(z, ~df %>% filter(Z == .x) %>% group_by(village) %>% summarise(Y.mean = mean(Y)))
#[[1]]
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  village Y.mean
#  <fct>    <dbl>
#1 a         800.
#2 b         300.
#
#[[2]]
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  village Y.mean
#  <fct>    <dbl>
#1 a         450.
#2 b         700.
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "  village     A     Z      Y
 1       a     1     1   500
 2       a     1     1   400
 3       a     1     0   800
 4       b     1     0   300
 5       b     1     1   700  ", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` to accomplish it:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(village) %>% 
  filter(Z == 1) %>% 
  summarise(Y_village = mean(Y))

## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  village Y_village
#  <chr>       <dbl>
#1 a             450
#2 b             700
```

To get all columns:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(village) %>% 
  filter(Z == 1) %>% 
  mutate(Y_village = mean(Y)) %>% 
  distinct(village, A, Z, Y_village)

## A tibble: 2 x 4
## Groups:   village [2]
#  village     A     Z Y_village
#  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 a           1     1       450
#2 b           1     1       700
```

#### data

```
df <- data_frame(village = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"),
                 A = rep(1, 5),
                 Z = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                 Y = c(500, 400, 800, 30, 700))
```

Comment: Thanks! I think your answer passes a column rather than a part of the tibble. For this toy example, I know it works, but I would like to have all columns in my function.

Comment: You want to keep all columns including `Y` or all columns with `Y_village`?